# How to create a custom installshield dialog skin?

Tags: installshield, installscript

I am trying to create an InstallScript project using InstallShield 2013 Authoring Tool. So far I have just been using the default dialog boxes and skins.  Now I need to now customize them to fit my needs, but I am finding the links in the help documentation to be lacking or broken.  I was wondering if anyone knows how to create custom dialog skins or can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Skin Customization Kit from [Flexera Software Product and License Center](https://flexerasoftware.subscribenet.com/control/inst/index)

Comment: In order to add a custom skin to a Installscript project you need to follow a couple of steps.  Once the skin has been created using the SkinCustomizationKit.exe you take the resulting file and copy it into the %Programfiles/InstallShield/2013/Skins directory.  Reload any IS project that might be open in VS or the IS IDE.  Go to User Interface->Dialogs->Skins and the custom skin should be available to use

Answer (score 7):

1. under "Project Assistant" tab, select "Installation Interview".
2. click on "Use custom images on dialogs" to specify your own images to replace "full screen image" and the "banner image" for the dialog.
   large image size can be set to 499x312; banner can be set to 499x58 (if original theme used is 'Classic' or similar.)
   https://docs.revenera.com/installshield28helplib/helplibrary/IDlgDialogImages.htm
3. till now, the dialog screen should look pretty good. But you will notice the InstallShield opening image (flash screen) is still using a default theme image. to solve that, create your own image (GIF format) to replace the original 'setup.gif' under the folder:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2022\Support\Themes\Classic Theme.
   (once again, all the image sizes and locations mentioned are based on the assumption that 'Classic theme of the dialog box is used)

Comment: However there are many themes if I replace the image only in classic theme how will it help? What I mean is, is there any location where we can set the image for flash screen?

Comment: I changed the image in installation screen by replacing the setup.gif image present in (C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2012Spring\Support\Themes\InstallShield Blue Theme) to the required image and it worked.